# Python How to change default version back from python 3.5 to python 2.7

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda

Recently, I just installed anaconda3 for python3, it works well. But then I found out that my python default version has been modified to python3.5 as well. When I type "python" in terminal, it appears like this

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55)
```

So I go and check my bash_profile, and found why it has been changed to python3.5:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 2.4.1 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 2.4.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/chengluli/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 2.4.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/chengluli/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

After I commented all the texts related to python3.5 and anaconda3. The default changes to python2.7.

**However, the problem I have now is anaconda3 is not working. When I type ipython notebook, error occurs.**

So I wonder how can I change default python version while having anaconda3 work properly? Or anaconda3 can only work when the default is python3.5. So I need to use anaconda2 instead? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the alias for the current user or create a new symlink to make it systemwide.

More information and Debian examples can be found here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Answer (score 0):

Download Anaconda2 instead, which uses Python 2.7.

When you removed the anaconda path .bashrc you removed ipython and all the other binaries from the system path. They're still on your system but you can't run them by just typing `ipython`, you'd have to run them from their location `./anaconda3/bin/ipython` or equivalent